# How to get document id on Cloud Firestore on flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

How to get document ID on Cloud Firestore?

[image]

```
  getCategoryId(String categoryName){
    var ref = _db.collection('categories')
        .where("categoryName",isEqualTo: categoryName);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this way..It's working.

```
  getCategoryId(String categoryName){
    var ref = _db.collection('categories')
        .where("categoryName",isEqualTo: categoryName).getDocuments();
    ref.then((v)=>print(v.documents[0].documentID));
}
```